# What is wrong with this simple python program? shutil error

Tags: python, shutil

I already got the wallpaper switcher working, but for whatever reason shutil.copy won't work. The program should set a different wallpaper for each day of the weak. I believe the filepaths are correct.

```
import time;
import shutil;
import ctypes;
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
wkd = localtime[6]

if wkd == 6:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\1.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\1\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")

elif wkd == 0:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\2.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\2\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")

elif wkd == 1:
    src = r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\3\backgrounddefault.jpg"
    dst = r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds"
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\3.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy2(src,dst)

elif wkd == 2:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\4.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\4\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")

elif wkd == 3:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\5.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\5\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")

elif wkd == 4:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\6.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\6\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")

elif wkd == 5:
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\7.jpg",0)
    shutil.copy(r"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\7\backgrounddefault.jpg",r"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\INFO\backgrounds")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Wallpaper\Program.py", line 21, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(src,dst)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\shutil.py", line 243, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\shutil.py", line 110, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\INFO\\backgrounds\\backgrounddefault.jpg'
```

Comment: Permission denied: Run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The way you run your code as a **User** is not have **all rights of System**. So you need to Run your code as a **Administrator** or a **User** which have **root rights** or **all rights of System.**

And code is work well as my end.